# Transform JavaScript object in RxJS pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I currently have the following piece of logic in typescript:

```
something.pipe(
  take(1),
  withLatestFrom(
    this.a$,
    this.b$
  ),
  tap(([, a, b]) => {
    const obj = {};
    a.forEach(
      x =>
        (obj[x.myKey.a] = x.myValue.map(record -> {
                      ...record,
                      quantity: 0,
                    }))
    );
    doSomething(object, b);
  })
);
```

This code works, but is quite verbose considering what it tries to achieve. I've been looking for a way to simplify the logic by better using RxJS operators, but can't figure out how. The main thing I'd like to improve is the part where I first create an empty JavaScript object (called `obj`) and then assign its values in a `forEach`. I've been looking into simplifying this logic using something that merges several JavaScript objects (`mergeMap`?):

```
const obj = a.mergeMap(x => {x.myKey.a: x.myValue.map(record -> {
                      ...record,
                      quantity: 0,
                    })});
```

Of course, the code in above snippet is not valid, since `mergeMap` must be used in the surrounding `pipe`, but I can't figure out how to. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You asked for a direction. You could look into the .reduce() method
    a.reduce((carry, currentValue) => { // functions }, {}// the initial object )

Comment: `tap` **don't** change the response, use `map`

Comment: mergeMap is an operator that maps values from one stream into new inner streams, then merges all the mapped streams together by subscribing to them all. Doesn't merge objects or anything like that.

Comment: @MrkSef Ah, I see, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned already, reduce is generally a good way of turning an array into a single value (be that a number, boolean, or object).

This should do it.

You'll notice some extra brackets. They're necessary, since curly braces denote both object literals as well as a block of code. Wrapping an object literal in braces removes that ambiguity.

```js
const obj = a.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => ({
    ...acc,
    [curr.myKey.a]: curr.myValue.map(record => ({
      ...record,
      quantity: 0,
    }))
  }), 
  {}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to T. van den Berg's hint to use `reduce`, I simplified it to the following:

```
const obj = a.reduce((acc, x) => {acc[x.myKey.a] = x.myValue.map(record -> {
                      ...record,
                      quantity: 0,
                    };
                    return acc;
                  }), {});
```

Comment: The accumulator  function also needs to return the accumulator.